# html имитация нажатия кнопки submit при выборе значения из списка

Tags: javascript, html, css

доброе время суток, коллеги!

на сайте есть список

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var form = document.querySelector('form')

  console.log('Yo!', form, form.querySelectorAll('input'));

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    e.preventDefault();

    var params = []

    var fields = form.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

      var name = fields[i].name;

      var value = fields[i].value;

      console.log('Added field', name, value);

      params.push(name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));

    }

    var newUrl = '?' + params.join('&');


    console.log('url Finnaly', newUrl);

    parent.window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      searchUrl: newUrl
    }), document.location.origin);

  })

});
```

```html
<select name="thelistForest" id="thelistForest" onChange="comboCommon(this, 'varForest')">
```

функция сomboCommon обрабатывает выбранное значение
и есть кнопка "Отправить"
при нажатии на которую срабатывает скрипт

выбранные данные передаются, страница обновляется. все хорошо.
вопрос: как мне имитировать нажатие кнопки при выборе значения из списка?

заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У формы есть [метод submit](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp), а у кнопки отправить - [метод click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var form = document.querySelector('form')
  console.log('Yo!', form, form.querySelectorAll('input'));
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var params = []
    var fields = form.querySelectorAll('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      var name = fields[i].name;
      var value = fields[i].value;
      console.log('Added field', name, value);
      params.push(name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));

    }
    var newUrl = '?' + params.join('&');
    console.log('url Finnaly', newUrl);
    parent.window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      searchUrl: newUrl
    }), document.location.origin);
  })
});
   
// Submit
const comboCommon = (that, string) => {
  document.forms[0].submit();
}

// Click
const comboCommon2 = e => {
  document.querySelector('form>input').click();
}
```

```html
<form>

<select name="thelistForest" id="thelistForest" onChange="comboCommon(this, 'varForest')">
<option>Submit111</option>
<option>Submit222</option>
</select>

<select onChange="comboCommon2()">
<option>Click111</option>
<option>Click222</option>
</select>

<input type='submit' value='Отправить'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Darth, огромное спасибо!                        все заработало